# Perl bootstrap parameter mismatch

Tags: perl, sqlite, installation

I'm using ActiveState Perl 5.8.8.  Just used PPM to upgrade DBD::SQLite from 1.08 to 1.25 and received this compilation error on first use:

DBD::SQLite object version 1.25 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.08 at C:/Perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 252.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the package, same result.  Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops, found a copy of the old DBD::SQlite in my local library.  Removed it and all is well.  Sorry for the trouble.